# How should I change the scene with animation by three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am learning three.js recently. I want to reach the effect:
When using mouse to click the top-right buttons, the scene will be changed with animation.

Please see the example in the source of Threejs http://www.georgeandjonathan.com/#2

Comment: It is just animating the camera I think

Comment: **1)** Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and consider providing a [`Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for the problem you're having. **2)** There are many, many resources available which have information relating to what you're trying to do. Please use teh search feature, as well as other internet resources